# HTML template in AngularJS like KnockoutJS

Tags: angularjs, knockout.js, angular-template

HTML templates can be used multiple times with supplied data as object in KnockoutJS, I am getting difficulties in finding the same feature with AngularJS. Take a look at below URL of KO documentation.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'person-template', data: buyer }"></div>
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'person-template', data: seller }"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="person-template">
    <h3 data-bind="text: name"></h3>
    <p>Credits: <span data-bind="text: credits"></span></p>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
     function MyViewModel() {
         this.buyer = { name: 'Franklin', credits: 250 };
         this.seller = { name: 'Mario', credits: 5800 };
     }
     ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
</script>
```

You can observe how "buyer" and "seller" are passed as object to template, and rendered accordingly with Knockout JS.

I want similar implementation with AngularJS. Take a look at below example.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="someId">{{name}}</script>

<ng-include src="'someId'" onload="name='FirstValue'" ></ng-include>
<ng-include src="'someId'" onload="name='SecondValue'" ></ng-include>
```

I tried something like above, but finally both ng-include will generate "test1" text. I want different result for both ng-include, for first "FirstValue" and for second "SecondValue"

Take a look at here: http://plnkr.co/edit/DQgPZ9GKKLnwSvOggY3M?p=preview

How can I pass data object to such html template and render accordingly?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reuse templates you can create [`directives`](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) which contain a scope.

**Template**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="someId.html"><span>{{name}}</span></script>
```

**Directive**

```
myApp.directive("myTemplate", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            name: "="
        },
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: "someId.html"
    };
});
```

**Usage**

```
<my-template name="name"></my-template>
```

**[Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/1bBmE0DlYRINkeX9r8S9?p=preview)**

Comment: I tried the way you have suggest in below plunker, please check and let me know if I am doing anything wrong, it's not working as I have followed the way you have suggested here.

http://plnkr.co/edit/DQgPZ9GKKLnwSvOggY3M?p=preview

Comment: The `templateUrl` must match the id of the template, and also the template must have one root element so if you wrap name in a `<span>{{name}}</span>` everything works correctly, see example