# Dynamically manipulating DOM element in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a requirement to render all the posts from my database by using AngularJS. I need to provide Edit functionality for each post that is visible to the user. Currently, I am doing this by using a 'edit-post' directive. Here is the linking function for that.

```
link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function () {
                var divId = $scope.$parent.post.meta.id + "Data";

                var html = $compile("<div class='editTextAreaDiv' id='" + divId + "'>" +
                            "<textarea  class='editTextArea' id='editBox' rows='3' ng-model='editedPostText' name='editedPostText'>" + $scope.$parent.post.meta.data + "</textarea><br />" +

                            "<span class='pull-right'>" +
                                "<input class='btn' type='button' value='Save'  ng-click='saveEditedPost(\"" + divId + "\")'/>" +
                                "<input class='btn' type='button' value='Cancel' ng-click='cancelEdit(\"" + divId + "\")'/>" +
                            "</span>" +
                        "</div>")($scope);
                $("#" + divId).html(html);
            });

}
```

I am manipulating DOM by dynamically adding a textarea and 2 buttons.

My question is whether this approach of dynamically manipulating DOM elements is preferable in Angular world. Or should I go for some other approach (like using ng-show/ng-hide directives to show/hide the textarea and 2 buttons).

Note: I preferred not to use ng-show/ng-hide since I didn't want to introduce an extra textarea and 2 buttons for every post.

Please guide me regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use [Directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

putting your HTML inside the javascript is bad, and breaks the idea behind angular which aims to separate the logic from the view, and keep your objects lossly-coupled.

see similar question here: [HTML template in AngularJS like KnockoutJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17214059/html-template-in-angularjs-like-knockoutjs)

Comment: So adding a textarea(using ng-show/ng-hide) for each post on the page is fine? For 100's of posts, it would mean adding that many textareas and buttons.

Comment: No, you would build one template that will be used for all your items.

Comment: Yes. But still all textareas would be loaded at compile time right? with the binded model values.